# Millions of requests and MariaDB vs. PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, mariadb

I do not ask for comparison. I already know what PostgreSQL and MariaDB is and differences.

I am looking this issue from another point. Such companies like **Facebook** uses **MySQL** (of course patched) but how can they handle millions of requests?

To be more clear; **PostgreSQL** has **PgPool** tool that caches and Re-Uses current connection for everyone as much client datas are the same. So, when a **PHP** application connects to PgPool 10.000 times, it actually uses few connections. This makes PostgreSQL available to millions of users at the same time without `max connection` error.

But on MariaDB/MySQL there is a `max_connection` setting points to `150`. Is it means only 150 client can connect to MariaDB/MySQL from same PHP Web Page? What should I do to handle for example millions of request from PHP to the MariaDB? If **2 millions** of users login at the same time to my site what will happen if my `max_connection` is `150`? Or, Better, Is there any equivalent for MariaDB like PgPool?

What kind of scenario would I apply in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql (combining with php) reuse a connection always when the connections it's already open of course.
So you have to consider your average query time (gen. 1 millisecond but it depends from your DB) and I hope great prosperity to your business, but 150 connections = 150*1000 =150kqps ... I think it's just good enough! I hope I gave you a good explanation.

P.S.
For understanding your current situation run this command on your db:

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
```